# Hello I am getting error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:" at eclipse IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing

I am getting error message Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: at newpackage.PG1.main(MyClass.java:12) while i have added all libraries of selenium and add them, can anyone please help me out whats the problem is this code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs8an.png)

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Edit your question to include your code as text, and whatever error message you get when you build it.

Comment: For a start, your source code has two `package` statements.  That's not valid in Java. In general, fix **all** of the compilation errors **before** you try to run your code.

Comment: Take note of the red Xs that Eclipse is showing you - they are errors that you need to fix before running the code. Look at the Problems view for more details about errors.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the second `package` declaration and the resolving errors. After that, run it again.